# SQL Server WHERE clause

Tags: sql-server-2008, where-clause

I have a SQL Server database and I want to define a query which return results based on only the first two numbers in a int column.

Something like:

```
SELECT * FROM myTable WHERE myIntColumn = 13%
```

So any rows with 13, 133, 134 and 1380 would be returned

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Nothing fancy, just change to varchar and pattern match.

```
SELECT * FROM myTable
  WHERE CAST(myIntColumn as varchar(10)) LIKE '13%'
```

You could integer divde by powers of 10 but it's a loop or recursion

```
;WITH cTE AS
(
    SELECT TOP 9
        POWER(10, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY column_id)) AS divisor
    FROM
        sys.columns
)
SELECT
   *
FROM
   myIntColumn
   JOIN
   cTE ON myIntColumn / divisor = 13
```

Answer (score 4):

You need to convert the number into a string:

```
SELECT * FROM myTable WHERE convert(varchar, myIntColumn) like '13%'
```

Do take into consideration that this query will probably not benefit from an index on `myIntColumn` field.

Comment: if performance is an issue consider adding a varchar column to the table which contains the pre-converted value. Add an index to this column and your queries should be much faster at the expense of a little extra storage.

Answer (score 1):

You don't have to explicitly cast the column (it will be done implicitly due to the LIKE)

```
SELECT * FROM myTable WHERE myIntColumn like '13%'
```

Just for consideration, you can use maths to achieve the same result, which could be faster

```
SELECT * FROM myTable
WHERE myIntColumn/NULLIF(POWER(10,LEN(myIntColumn)-2),0) = 13
```